# Windows reboot, possible BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, minidumps

Hi I'm having some trouble with a computer that reboots. I haven't seen the bsod myself but user has said it bsoded butt every time when I've gotten to the computer it has already rebooted and is stuck saying it can't find any boot media.

Repowering the system and it boots up fine and a few hours later the same thing. This is a computer in a manufacturing environment so our heatsinks and fans tend to get clogged by oil residue so usually when we have system failures it's related to this. The cpu fan was kinda broken but It's fixed now and I've been monitoring the cpu temps and so far it hasn't gone over 45*C.

I'm inclined to believe that something has taken damage because overheating but hp system diagnostics returns everything fine. And I'm unsure how to further debug the hardware atm.

Another thing is that I can't find any bsod minidumps, in windows/minidump I only got two files that are 6+ years old which I find a little weird.

The computer is on a network and users that's not admin haven't got access to C:/ and for example the desktop is a shared folder between several computers that's on a server and I'm wondering if any potential dumps might be found here somewhere instead?

Any tips on how to find some sort of crash log or further help to debug would be appreciated.

Forgot to add that it's Windows Xp 32bit the computer is running.

Comment: Sharing the specific version of Windows might be useful?

Comment: Windows Xp 32bit

Comment: Without the dmp file for the BSOD, there isn't much we can help you with, I don't see enough information to even guess what the problem is.  Is just reinstalling Windows an option?

Comment: I've had the same symptoms with a failing hard disk. Do you have smart data for the disk?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the System Event Logs?

Comment: I can the collowing cmd commands, wmic then diskdrive get status and it said that alias couldn't be found so I guess I don't have smart data for the disc.

Event log showed several errors and warnings, alternating between atapi error and disk warning. Considering that it had trouble finding boot media when it rebooted is it farfetched to guess that the problem might lie with the disk? I'll try and check all the cables next and then perhaps plug in the disk to another computer and run a checkdisk on it?

Comment: You seem to be on the right lines there.